# How to inspect HTTP status code and a specific URL from Network Inspector under Firefox using Tampermonkey Userscript

Tags: javascript, firefox, greasemonkey, tampermonkey, userscripts

Is it possible to extract any particular link from the Network tab under Firefox Inspect Element by using Tampermonkey Userscript. I would also like to check if the HTTP status code of the URL that is present there, so if it is a specific value say 200 or 206 then only I will copy that url into clipboard or do whatever with it.

Does Userscript allow us to get URLs under network tab of FF or Chrome?